# Not able to disable block cache without affecting Magento FPC

Tags: magento2.3, full-page-cache, custom-block

I have created a custom block where I am showing the number of items in the cart and also loggedin the customer name. I am getting correct count and customer name on checkout page.But not on any other pages such as Product page, home page etc.
This is because I have enabled full page caching. If I disable FPC then everything works fine. But I want to keep FPC and also need to show this count on other pages. How it can be done? 
I have already tried many codes like  $this->_isScopePrivate = true; in constructor. But it's not working. I am using Magento 2.3.1.
Below is sample code:

```
class ShoppingCart extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;

    }



    /**
     * Get quote object associated with cart. By default it is current customer session quote
     *
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote
     */
    public function getQuoteData()
    {
        $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
        if (!$this->hasData('quote')) {
            $this->setData('quote', $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote());
        }
        return $this->_getData('quote');
    }

    public function getMyCustomMethod(){
        return "test function callecd";
    }
}
```

and calling in logo.phtml page as.

```
$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Rbj\Customer\Block\ShoppingCart');
$quote =  $blockObj->getQuoteData();
$itemsCount = $quote->getItemsCount();
$itemsCount = $blockObj->getMyCustomMethod();
```

Please advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can make that specific block cache disable.

Comment: Yes, we can. But then full page caching does not work for all pages.

Comment: Adding below line in xml file prevents full page cache work.
<block class="Rbj\Customer\Block\ShoppingCart" name="customBlock" cacheable="false"/>

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 has special system for display personal/private customer data on the cachable pages.

Shortly: magento use additional ajax query to retrieve all needed private data (including data you needed). Than you can use this data from js.

[Private content in magento](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html)

In the Luma theme the minicart works using this way.

Here is additional query to private data:

http://prntscr.com/o7iwx4

Here is layout for minicart:
`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

Block
`Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar`
has inside js-layout which conteins js-components.

You can find them in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web`

Comment: Can you demonstrate?

Comment: I'll update my answer